# How to use collectionGroup in @angular/fire 7+

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-security, angularfire2

I would do a search form using keywords, I can do it with more ancient versions of @angular/fire but not with this one.

Always the same error :

> FirebaseError : missing or insufficient permissions

I've tried to implement a collectionGroup new function inside my Angular app but it shows the error above.

Then I've tried to create a firebase function to return my collectionGroup but I can't re-use the object because it's not @angular/fire, it's purely firebase, right ?

Inside my component :

```
import {
  collectionData,
  collectionGroup,
  DocumentData,
  Firestore,
  query,
  where,
} from '@angular/fire/firestore';

search() {
if (this.searchForm.value.search.length) {
  let substances = collectionGroup(this.afStore, 'substance');
  // ERROR FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.
  let query$ = query(
    substances,
    where('keywordsName', 'array-contains', this.searchForm.value.search)
  );
  let res = collectionData(query$);
  let res$ = res.pipe(
    map((families: DocumentData[]) => {
      families.forEach((family: DocumentData) => {
        family['color'] = this.riskReduction.generateRandomColor();
      });
      return families;
    })
  );
  this.riskReduction.setSubstances(res$);
} else {
  this.riskReduction.setSubstances(this.riskReduction.getSubstances());
}
}
```

Edit :
Else I tried with the function :

```
/**
 * ANCHOR: Search a substance
 */

export const searchSubstance = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  try {
    const ref = admin.firestore().collectionGroup('substance');
    return <BasicResponse>{
      status: 'success',
      data: { substances: ref.get() },
    };
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    return <BasicResponse>{ status: 'error', message: e };
  }
});
```

thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

The error:

**PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions**

Means that this exception is thrown because the Firebase servers rejected the operation, this can be fixed by changing the [Cloud Firestore Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started)
You can try the following rules (only for testing):

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
 match /databases/{database}/documents {
   match /{document=**} {
     allow read, write: if true;
   }
 }
}
```

The rules are only recommended for testing purposes since anyone that has your project ID can read or write. You can implement several security measures, here is an [excellent article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-fix-firestore-error-permission-denied-missing-or-insufficient-permissions-777d591f404) by Alex Mamo (a member of the community) that you can use to implement several other more secure security rules.

**1st UPDATE**

Since we are retrieving results from a [collection group](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#collection_group_queries_and_security_rules) consisting of collections, you need to use [recursive wildcard {name=**}](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#recursive_wildcards)

When using the recursive wildcard syntax, the wildcard variable will contain the entire matching path segment, even if the document is located in a deeply nested subcollection. For example, the rules listed above would match a document located at `/cities/SF/landmarks/coit_tower`, and the value of the document variable would be `SF/landmarks/coit_tower`.

In version 2 of the security rules, recursive wildcards match zero or more path items. `match/cities/{city}/{document=**}` matches documents in any sub-collections and documents in the `cities` collection.

You must opt-in to version 2 by adding rules_version = '2'; at the top of your security rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // Matches any document in the cities collection as well as any document
    // in a subcollection.
    match /cities/{city}/{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if <condition>;
    }
  }
}
```

You can have at most one recursive wildcard per match statement, but in version 2, you can place this wildcard anywhere in the match statement. For example:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // Matches any document in the songs collection group
    match /{path=**}/songs/{song} {
      allow read, write: if <condition>;
    }
  }
}
```

We can avoid this error altogether by implementing [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup), this [will bypass the security rules](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-fix-firestore-error-permission-denied-missing-or-insufficient-permissions-777d591f404) entirely.

I also find this [github theard](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/679) that explains how to avoid getting this error doing the following:

1. Go to IAM and admin
2. Select the Service accounts menu on the left hand side
3. Under 'Service accounts for project '[Project Name]' copy the Email of the account that has 'App Engine default service account' under its Name column (should be [project_id]@appspot.gserviceaccount.com).
4. Select the IAM menu from the left hand side
5. Click +ADD on the very top (next to the 'IAM' title)
6. In the field 'New principals' paste the service account email copied in point 3
7. Select the role 'Firebase Admin SDK Administrator Service Agent'
8. Click SAVE.

Comment: I'm using the following rules :

    rules_version = '2';
    service cloud.firestore {
      match /databases/{database}/documents {
        match /risk-reduction/{familyParam} {
         allow read, write: if true;
        }
         match /risk-reduction/{familyParam}/class/{classParam} {
         allow read, write: if true;
        }
         match /risk-reduction/{familyParam}/class/{classParam}/substance/{substanceParam} {
      allow read, write: if true;
        }
    }

but it has no effect when trying with /{document=**}

Comment: @F3LENYR: I edited my answer and added additional information, hope it's useful.